# Moving Text Area Based on button click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html, dom

I have several textarea with two buttons on each:

- 1) Move Up
- 2) Move Down

As the button name describes, When the moveup button is clicked the textarea should go one level up similarly for movedown click the textarea should move one level up.
How Can I achieve that in Angular.

```
<div>
  <textarea  #first_text_area></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="./assets/up.png" #text_area_1 (click)="moveUp()">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="./assets/down.png" #text_area_1 (click)="moveDown()">
</div>
```

Similarly I have many text area with same code. How can I implement the functionalities in `moveUp()` and `moveDown()`. [example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJHKE.jpg)

Comment: Please post what you ahve tried so far and consider creating a [mcve] on stackblitz.

Comment: do you want to change the height of text area?

Comment: Not the height I want to move the whole textarea on button click

Comment: @abdulrauf Do you want to reorder the textareas?

Comment: Yes @Jan exactly I want to reorder the position of text area..

Comment: @abdulrauf I think, the best way is to use styles. Reorder with css.